# Handling multiple response types from same API in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httpclient

I am fairly new to Angular. I've been working on a service which fetches certain data from an API and returns an observable. The API can return two types of JSON responses, an array of custom data type or a custom error code and message in case of some internal error in the server. I have created two interfaces, say `I1` and `I2`, according to the two possible responses. Both the JSON responses returned by the API also follow the same structures respectively.

```
interface I1 {
  responseData: customData[]
}

interface I2 {
  errorCode: number,
  errorMessage: string
}
```

For the service itself, I want to write a function which first fetches the data and checks it for the type received. If the type is `I1`, then it will return the observable of the array in `I1` or if the type is `I2`, then it will log the error on console and also return the error object. I have written a function in the service class:

```
APIResponse: I1 | I2;

getData(): Observable<CustomData[] | I2> {
  this.http.get<I1 | I2>('url/to/api').subscribe(res => {
    this.APIResponse = res;
  });

  if('errorCode' in this.APIResponse) {
    console.log(this.APIResponse.errorCode);
    return of(this.APIResponse);
  }
  else if('responseData' in APIResponse) {
    return of(this.APIResponse.responseData);
  }
}
```

Now this code shows errors while compiling because the type of `this.APIResponse` is not same as expected by the function for its return value. I can change the return type of the function to `Observable<I1 | I2>` but then I will not be able to return just the array. I cannot change the API structure in any way. I have tried assigning the APIResponse in case of error to an intermediate variable of type `I2` and then returning it from the function, but it does not let me assign type `'I1 | I2'` to a type `'I2'`.

How should I proceed from here to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your getData method to :-

```
getData(): Observable<CustomData[] | I2> {
  return this.http.get('url/to/api').pipe(map((res : I1|I2) => {
    if('errorCode' in res) {
       this.APIResponse = res;  
       console.log(this.APIResponse.errorCode);
       return res;
    } else {
         this.APIResponse = res;
         return res.responseData;
    }
  }));
}
```

Any where you want to use this method, use it like :-

```
getData().subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Since `I1` is an interface and not a class, `instanceof` will not work. Also, when I write `this.APIResponse.responseData` it shows an error saying 
"Property 'responseData' does not exist on type 'I1 | I2'. 
Property 'responseData' does not exist on type 'I2'."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are subscribing in service, but it is anti-pattern.

If `APIResponse` variable is only used in `getData()` function just to create a new observable, then you don't need it.

To log response or to perform any side effects, use `tap` operator.

```
getData(): Observable<CustomData[] | I2> {
    return this.http.get<I1 | I2>('url/to/api').pipe(
      map(res => {
        if ('responseData' in res) {
          return res.responseData;
        } else if ('errorCode' in res) {
          return res;
        }
      }),
      tap(res => {
        // Side effects

        if ('errorCode' in res) {
          console.log(res.errorCode);
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

In case, if you are using `APIResponse` variable and want to assign response to it, you have to do it in `tap` operator as this is side effect.

```
  tap(res => {

    // Assign value to APIResponse;

    this.APIResponse = res;
  })
```

Finally, to get data from server, subscribe to `getData()` observable stream in your component.

`this._service.getData().subscribe(data => { // do what you want with data })`

If your service sends error response with code other than `2xx`, then you can either use `catchError` operator or use http options to get full control over request.